# How to Convert an Array-Like String into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift4

I have a string that has the following value: " "OneV", "TwoV", "ThreeV" " 
I was wondering if there was a way to take this string and convert it into an array that would have the follwing value: ["OneV", "TwoV", "ThreeV"]

Comment: which language are you using? what is the type of your string? are they all grouped in a single variable? type of the variable?

Comment: @ameerosein The language is Swift. It's in the tags of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let aString = " \"OneV\", \"TwoV\", \"ThreeV\" "  
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
let stringArr = newString.components(separatedBy: ",")
print(stringArr)
```

If the sting not contains `"` inside string then

```
let aString = "OneV,TwoV,ThreeV"  
let stringArr = aString.components(separatedBy: ",")
print(stringArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

swift

```
let str = "\"OneV\", \"TwoV\", \"ThreeV\""
let ary = str.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into an array, you can use

```
string.split(separator: ",")
```

This will turn string from "1,2,3,4,5" to ["1","2","3","4","5"]

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the string with two pointers and look for characters **between** two double quotes (or any character of your choice) :

```
func substrings(of str: String, between char: Character) -> [String] {
    var array = [String]()

    var i = str.startIndex

    while i < str.endIndex {
        while i < str.endIndex, str[i] != char {
            i = str.index(after: i)
        }

        if i == str.endIndex { break }

        i = str.index(after: i)

        var j = i

        while j < str.endIndex, str[j] != char { 
            j = str.index(after: j) 
        }

        guard j < str.endIndex else { break }

        if j > i { array.append(String(str[i..<j])) }

        i = str.index(after: j)
    }

    return array
}
```

And here are some use cases :

```
let s1 = "\"OneV\", \"TwoV\", \"ThreeV\""
substrings(of: s1, between: "\"") //["OneV", "TwoV", "ThreeV"]

let s2 = "\"OneV\", \"TwoV\", \"Thr"
substrings(of: s2, between: "\"") //["OneV", "TwoV"]

let s3 = "|OneV|, |TwoV|, |ThreeV|"
substrings(of: s3, between: "|") //["OneV", "TwoV", "ThreeV"]

let s4 = "abcdefg"
substrings(of: s4, between: ",") //[]
```